# What is the appropriate resolution for a 4x2 tarpaulin and a invitation card?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, cs6, layout

I was asked by my teacher to design her son a birthday tarpaulin and also a invitation card. It's my first time designing this kind of large project as I'm more familiar in smaller scale ones such as an ID.

How much resolution should i put and what is the appropriate color mode for the tarp and invitation so it wouldn't be pixelated?

I'm planning to use photoshop as it's the software that I'm comfortable with

Comment: If I was using Photoshop and I am assuming this is a 48" W x 24" H Tarp. I would design at 48" W x 24" H, 100 resolution, and in CMYK. Or design in RGB and convert to CMYK if you need certain blending modes. The invitation could be designed at 300 resolution if you're using Photoshop for that as well.